# Java button is working strangely

Tags: java, swing, button

I am using Swing to build a GUI in Java. The code to make the button and add it is like this:

```
    //Create a button
    JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    exitButton.setSize(90, 40);
    exitButton.setLocation(800, 450);
    exitButton.setVisible(true);

    //Adding components
    window.getContentPane().add(exitButton);
```

When I run the app, the button appears in the whole window, sometimes appears as its intended and sometimes doesn't come. Is this some sort of java bug or a prob with my `sdk`. In case you wish to know what sort of window it is,

```
//Create a window
JFrame window = new JFrame("First Window");
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
window.setVisible(true);
window.setSize(1000, 550);
window.setLocation(150, 150);
```

It's all within static void main. BTW, how I get the button to close the window through `System.exit(0);` (I am a beginner and this is my first self-written GUI)

Comment: You need a layout for your window.

Comment: If you're a beginner in making GUIs, you'd best make them using a visual editor. Then, check the code to see what's happening 'under water'.

Comment: @Heuster already used NetBeans's GUI builder, but it doesn't let me edit (most of) the code and creates problems

Comment: @Heuster _If you're a beginner in making GUIs, you'd best make them using a visual editor._ Hum, no. Using GUI builder without understanding Swing will only lead to 2 things: stay a beginner in  GUI forever, and create ugly UI's with hard to maintain code. The right answer is to follow the Swing tutorials. For example, the Visual guide for LayoutManager.

Comment: The default LayoutManager of the content pane of the JFrame, is `BorderLayout`. Check out how to use LayoutManager's in Swing (and nesting them into each other). Moreover, the line `window.setVisible(true);` should be the last line in your code or you will need to call `revalidate(); repaint()` on the `JFrame`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You must check your layout, if you want to use custom position for your components, set Layout as null and use the `setBounds(x,y,weight,height)` method.

```
JFrame window = new JFrame("First Window");
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
window.setLayout(null);

JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
exitButton.setBounds(15,45,150,30);//This is just an example
exitButton.setVisible(true);
```

Best regards.

Comment: null-layout is never the right answer, only the worst advice one can give in Swing. The right answer is to properly use LayoutManager's.

Comment: I know it is not the best to do that, but in some places or schools, when some teachers start to teach Java and swing, they start with the null Layout to make the students work with coordinates to get used to it and then work with layouts as you mentioned. I put myself in the first case. Since I think he can be a student looking for help in this kind of scenario.

Comment: @Marcelo Tataje works cool. Guess setBounds(x, y, weight, height) is (x, y, width, height). Well yes, I am a student, just in my 9th standard at school.

Comment: yes, sorry, it is width. Pleased to help you. If this is the right answer for you, check it pllease to help other students to find it and prevent them to ask the same again. Thanks!

Comment: @PratikAnand Old habits die hard. When people start to use `setbounds()` etc... they get used to it and keep on reproducing it everywhere. I don't care if teachers start with null-layout, they are just wrong and it only shows they have poor knowledge of Java Swing. Using `setBounds` is not simpler than using an appropriate LayoutManager, on the contrary.

Comment: I don't share the same opinion. If you don't care it is up to you. As I mentioned in some schools the teachers can have a lot of knowledge on Java, but they just use the setBounds to show how coordinates work. Then immediately changes to LayoutManager, I use LayoutManager. My teacher started the Swing class taking 10 minutes to explain and show samples of setBounds, the rest of time was LayoutManager and I still use LayoutManager for 5 years, if the student get used to setBounds is his lack of knowledge and not the teacher's fault.

Answer (score 1):

You need a layout. See [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Also please check my tutorials [here.](http://easyjavatutorial.weebly.com/swing--awt.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got this sample code. This might be helpful Simple swing buttons

```
package com.ack.gui.swing.simple;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleSwingButtons extends JFrame {
  public static void main( String[] argv ) {
    SimpleSwingButtons myExample = new SimpleSwingButtons( "Simple Swing Buttons" );
  }

  public SimpleSwingButtons( String title ) {
    super( title );
    setSize( 150, 150 );
    addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing( WindowEvent we ) {
        dispose();
        System.exit( 0 );
      }
    } );
    init();
    setVisible( true );
  }

  private void init() {
    JPanel my_panel = new JPanel();
    my_panel.setLayout( new GridLayout( 3, 3 ) );
    for( int i = 1; i < 10; i++ ) {
      ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon( i + ".gif" );
      JButton jb = new JButton( icon );
      jb.setToolTipText( i + ".gif" );
      my_panel.add( jb );
    }
    getContentPane().add( my_panel );
    my_panel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder() );
  }
}
```

courtesy [Java.happycodings](http://www.java.happycodings.com/Java_Swing/code38.html)

Comment: Another website I need to ignore: no need to extend `JFrame`, use `pack` iso `setSize`, UI is not run on the EDT